# Error while embedding Flutter into existing ios app

Tags: ios, flutter, embed

I've followed the guide at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps. The only difference on this project is that pod was already initialized. When i include

```
flutter_application_path = '../my_flutter'
eval(File.read("#{flutter_application_path}/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb"))
```

into podfile it stops building the project saying:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h
```